# How to change email address in org-mode publish postamble?

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

When I publish a project, the sitemap postamble looks like this. How can I change this email address?

```
                Email: douhua@joseichous-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customise `user-mail-address` to add your own Email address.  All Emacs packages and extension including Org Mode will pick it up.